# .NET Windows control for editing XML/XSL?

Tags: .net, xml, editor, xslt

Apologies if this has been asked before. Had a quick search and there's nothing that answers my question 100%.

I've got some XSL stored in the database which I want the user to be able to edit within my .NET Windows application. I could just stick it into a multi-line textbox but then I don't get anything like auto-indent, colour-coding etc. Does anyone know of a .NET control I can use to achieve this? I'd ideally like to emulate the experience you get when editing an XML file in the Visual Studio IDE, but I realise this is probably unrealistic. At the bare minimum, I'd like it to have the text indent nicely. I'm not too worried about the validation of the XSL/XML itself - I can sort that myself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but there is code available on [CodePlex for an XML editor](http://gregsxmleditor.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx) called Greg's XML Editor.  It's not a control, but you could certainly look at the code and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit older but I did a simple XSL editor control a while back. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/XSLEditor.aspx